# Best Algorithm to convert one asset to another

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have in my Java program different pairs of financial assets, like `EURUSD`, `EURGBP`, `EURCHF` etc ...

To be more specific these are the pairs that I have:

```
EURUSD, EURGBP, EURCHF, XAUUSD, XAUXAG, XAGUSD 
XAGNZD, AUDCHF, AUDHKD, CADHKD, CADSGD, NZDCAD 
SGDHKD
```

I need to find the shortest chain of conversion for pairs not available in my list.

For example, if I am required to have `EUR` converted to `NZD` (so I would need the `EURNZD` pair), as you can see it's not present in my list.

To make this conversion I could use the following two conversion chains (there are even more than just these twos):

```
chain1: EURUSD->USDXAU->XAUXAG->XAGNZD
chain2: EURUSD->USDCHF->CHFAUD->AUDHKD->HKDCAD->CADNZD
```

So, among these two conversion chains, I would choose the number 1 , being the shortest among the ones available.

My question is, could you be so kind to suggest the best algorithm to find this shortest path? Could you kindly suggest a pseudocode of it?

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on a graph can do this, using the currencies as nodes and connecting two nodes when you can perform a conversion between them (it will be an undirected graph of course).

The pseudocode, from the wikipedia page I liked above, is

```
1  procedure BFS(G,v) is
2      create a queue Q
3      create a vector set V
4      enqueue v onto Q
5      add v to V
6      while Q is not empty loop
7         t ← Q.dequeue()
8         if t is what we are looking for then
9            return t
10        end if
11        for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(t) loop
12           u ← G.adjacentVertex(t,e)
13           if u is not in V then
14               add u to V
15               enqueue u onto Q
16           end if
17        end loop
18     end loop
19     return none
20 end BFS
```

Where G is the graph and v is the node you are starting from (EUR, in your example). You should slightly modify this to keep track of the previously visited node when adding it to Q (row 15) so that you can reconstruct the path when you find the target node (row 9).

Comment: Do you think this one is the less computationally expensive ? I mean principally in terms of the number of istructions needed and, secondly, in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I think that some clever trick with matrices or something of that kind _could_ be more efficient, but you will probably have a small graph so it won't be that big deal (I guess, without knowing the rest of your project)